# Linq to SQL Delete child and its relationships while Deleting Parent

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

The relationships in my case 
Photo -PhotoId
PhotoGroupsMap - MapingId(PK), PhotoId(FK with Photo)
PhotoShare - ShareId(PK),PhotoId(FK with Photo)
PhotoGroupComment - MapingId (FK with PhotoGroupsMap)

And i am using LinqSql for deletion and i want to Delete a Photo Object and i used the code

```
  Photoset _item = (from item in dbContext.Photos
                              where ....
                              select item).SingleOrDefault();

            //remove all Photo Share Entries
            dbContext.PhotosetShareMaps.DeleteAllOnSubmit(_item.PhotoShareMaps);
           //remove all Photo Group entries
            dbContext.PhotoGroups.DeleteAllOnSubmit(_item.PhotoGroups);
```

But how can i delete all Comments Associated with Groups? Since in this case if am trying to Delet Some Photo which is in some groups and the group contains some comment row , i am getting error (Since i am not removeing comments ). How can i remove that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try cascading deletion of "Comments" with the deletion of "Group".To get more information about cascading delete please refere tho this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27577/Cascading-Deletes-in-LINQ-to-SQL)